# how to solve the "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'" error

Tags: python, pandas, youtube-data-api, string-conversion, unsupportedoperation

I am working on some issues of YouTube API that allow me to estimate the influence of the informative side of each video (like, dislike and views count) in forming the user's opinion.

```
dff=pd.read_csv('VideosPolarity.csv')
print(dff)
print(dff.columns)

nv=len(dff) # video number
gamma=0.3
polarity=dff['polarity']
dislike=dff['dislikeCount']
like=dff['likeCount']
view=dff['viewCount']
viewNb=len(view)
channelId=dff['channelId'].unique()
users=len(channelId)

sumpolarity=polarity.sum(axis = 0, skipna = True)

avpolarity=sumpolarity/users

VOpinion=[]
for k in range(0,nv):
    value=(((like[k]-dislike[k])/viewNb)*round(avpolarity,1))*round(polarity[k],1)
    VOpinion.append(value)

VideoOpinion=gamma*sum(VOpinion)

print('VideoOpinion:',VideoOpinion)
```

but I faced this problem

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-aadb106341f9> in <module>
 23 VOpinion=[]
 24 for k in range(0,nv):
 ---> 25     value=(((like[k]-dislike[k])/viewNb)*round(avpolarity,1))*round(polarity[k],1)
 26     VOpinion.append(value)
 27 

 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

can anyone suggest a solution for me?

Comment: Minus is not defined for strings (unlike plus).

Comment: `like[k]-dislike[k]` are both strings, you cannot use `-` between two string instances. Check what you have defined under `like` and `dislike` since you are referring to them via index, if they are a string you are trying to subtract a `char` by a `char` which is not supported.

Comment: Try casting `like[k]` and `dislike[k]` to `float`.

Comment: @CamiloMartínez Isn't `pd.read_csv()` supposed to parse numbers in the CSV automatically?

Comment: @PacketLoss `like` and `disllike` come from the pandas df that was created with `pd.read_csv()`. Doesn't it parse numeric fields automatically?

Comment: @Barmar, I think it should, but the error seems to suggest otherwise. Or perhaps, there are "invalid" numbers inside the .csv

Comment: @CamiloMartínez That's what I suspect as well. If there are non-numbers in those fields, calling `float()` will also get an error. The OP needs to check the CSV to see what else is in those columns.

Comment: @Barmar actually it's what I have already done, calling float() did not change anything, and  I used to parse numbers from csv automatically but this time it didn't work.

Comment: Print `k` in the loop, then you'll know which row of the file is causing the error. Then check that line.